# How to launch a Java program in CMD?

Tags: java, windows

I need to run a JAR file from the command prompt. Basically I need to use the following command on startup: `java -jar jar-file-name.jar`, but how?

**Some more details:**

I need a program launcher that will launch my program in cmd.
Example code:

```
class hello_world{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
  }
}
```

How can I run this automatically in cmd without using `java -jar jar-file-name.jar`?

Comment: What kind of cmd  you want launch from your program?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run jar file in command prompt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774970/run-jar-file-in-command-prompt)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a JAR file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238145/how-to-run-a-jar-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open you Terminal/Command console... in the folder where you have the jar that you want to execute and then write:

```
java -jar jar-file-name.jar
```

Otherwise, as Steven C suggested, make a batch file `jar-file-name.bat` with the command above. Remember the path of the file.

To make a batch file, you just need to create a txt file with the command above, save it and rename it with the `.bat` extension. Double click it and enjoy your Java app.

If you want to merge the batch file and the jar one, try to give a look at this [How to create a Java application which can be run by a click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288440/how-to-create-a-java-application-which-can-be-run-by-a-click)

Comment: My program works perfectly in eclipse console. I want that if I start my program it will open my program automatically in cmd

Comment: okay, but can I put jar file and bat file together to one file?

Comment: [Added to answer] Give a check at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288440/how-to-create-a-java-application-which-can-be-run-by-a-click

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done, simply open your command prompt and type in `java -jar jarname.jar`. Now you're good to go!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute a Jar file on startup you can:

***Windows Environment***

**First Method:**

go to Start/Run and then write and write REGEDIT

Go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/MICROSOFT/Windows/Current Version/Run

Append the Path to your JAR file.

**Second Method**

Add your JAR file into START/ALL PROGRAMS/Autostart

***Linux Environment***

On Linux a quick way should be:

Create a script in **/etc/init.d/** to start the jar.

Remember to add & to the command. In this way the java process will run in background.

The start script should be

```
#!/bin/bash

java -jar myapp.jar &
```

If I didn't understand the question, I'm sorry. When I read on startup I've interpreted in this way.