# Making a Java Console Application

Tags: java, console-application

I wonder if it's possible to create a java console application where someone can download my packages, run and use that application in Command Line/Terminal or with some other console application. 
I am very well versed in Java & the reason I'm asking is, I have a chess game which I have made to be run in command line, but how do I get it to run like an application?
To wit: On a mac, just like one who has Home brew can download formulas and use their specific commands to begin and run them, how can I do this for an already made application. Do I need a config file? Or is it just good to go as it is.

So I don't want someone to download the package and have to use the "javac/java" command to compile and run it, but can just say something like "run chess" and it does so. Any help or resources would be appreciated

Comment: Look for the key word *packaging* online and that is mostly what you are looking for your application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a Java application which can be run by a click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288440/how-to-create-a-java-application-which-can-be-run-by-a-click)

Answer (score -1):

You need to convert your .jar to .exe

There is a lot of software doing this, for example JSmooth.
You need to choose the starting application class and then run it.

Comment: .exe seems to be the way to go about this as per online resources. I don't have a .jar file(I made the application from scratch using vscode and eventually moved it into packages). Maybe I'll try setting a .jar file in an IDE (Eclipse/Intelli J maybe). and then convert to .exe and see what happens. Thanks

Comment: The question specifically mentioned running on a Mac - EXE compilation will not help.

Comment: Online resources didn't say .exe was windows only. Thanks for pointing that out.